# How to assert returning object in Java Springbok Unit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I want to assert the object which is returned from the method that I am testing in Junit using Assertions.AssertEquals but its giving test case failure even though two objects are same.

`Expected :Customer{Id=1, Name='ABC', Price=350, Type='ABC'} Actual   :Customer{Id=1, Name='ABC', Price=350, Type='ABC'}`

This is the unit test case

```
@Test
public void getCustomerById_Test(){
    Dishes test1 = repo.getById(1);
    assertEquals(ExpectedObject,ActualObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit method `assertEquals` simply uses `equals` method of your class to compare the objects - you have to implement the method properly for the assertion to work correctly. You can read more about implementing `equals` in multiple online sources, for example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts).

If you don't want to implement `equals` in the verified class, you can also use `assertEquals` to compare object fields you're interested in, like so:

```java
assertEquals(7, actual.getSomeValue());
assertEquals("abcd", actual.getOtherValue());
```

If you added the AssertJ library, you could use it's `usingRecursiveComparison` method - for details refer to [the documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison).